# How do i Multiply the Value of a readonly input field and display the result in another field

Tags: javascript, html

I have Three input fields, When you input BTC amount in the first field, it gives you the BTC equivalent in USD. Then i added a hidden input field which holds a specific value, let's say "460", Now i want the BTC equivalent in USD to Multiply the "460" and give the result in a readonly input field. Below the code demonstrating my explanation.

```js
$(".form-control").keyup(function() { //input[name='calc']
  let convFrom;
  if ($(this).prop("name") == "btc") {
    convFrom = "btc";
    convTo = "usd";
  } else {
    convFrom = "usd";
    convTo = "btc";
  }
  $.getJSON("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/usd.json",
    function(data) {
      var origAmount = parseFloat($("input[name='" + convFrom + "']").val());
      var exchangeRate = parseInt(data.bpi.USD.rate_float);
      let amount;
      if (convFrom == "btc")
        amount = parseFloat(origAmount * exchangeRate);
      else
        amount = parseFloat(origAmount / exchangeRate);
      $("input[name='" + convTo + "']").val(amount.toFixed(2));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://stacksnippets.net/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="number" name="btc" class="form-control" id="validationTooltip02" placeholder="BTC">
  <input type="number" name="usd" class="form-control" id="a" onkeyup="add()" placeholder="USD" readonly>
```

The for the multiplication, i added onkeyup function to the USD field,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function add() {
  var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("a").value);
  var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("b").value)
  document.getElementById("c").value = x * y;
}
    </script>
```

then tried to collect the result by ID into a field using `<input name="amount" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="0.00000" id="c" aria-label="0.00000" readonly>`

This works if i remove readonly in the USD field and type directly but does not work with the result of the BTC to USD sum in the field when it's readonly. I hope i was able to explain this. Please help as i am not an expert.

Comment: Isn't the problem due to the fact that you dont have any element with and id b?

Comment: Also, why launch the `add` function on keyup on your second input, which user will never type in? You could do it in the form-control keyup function you're already using?

Comment: i have it in the main script, just mistakenly didn't include it here  <input type="hidden" id="b" value="465">

Comment: why you are using a keyup function a readonly input ? Its not clear how the final results would look like ?

Comment: And can you tell me how to add the multiplication function in the form-control keyup am already using ? Tried to the best of my knowledge and could not get it right.

Comment: @AlwaysHelping, Even When i remove the readonly, it does not matter. The final result is that, i want to multiply the result that goes in the USD field when you type into the BTC field with the hidden input value which is "460" and then display the result in the last input field.

Comment: was about to post a better solution. Looks like you got the answer ;/

Comment: @AlwaysHelping I don't think it would be a bad idea to get a better solution. What i got already works to an extent, however the Multiplication answer does not include decimals, e.g 4785.2 instead it just approximates to 4786 which is wrong when dealing with BTC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up `jQuery` and `JS` together ideally stick with one to avoid confusions. You do not need a separate function add the third input value multiplied by the `second` value.

You can do all that in your `API` call function. In addition to get the `decimals` you need to use `toFixed()` on the `final` third input `amount` as well.

Moreover, i would suggest for better **user experience** use `.on` function with `input` which is better then `key-up` since you have `input` type number. You can use `increment` your number by the click on increase in your input and the new values and total will be reflected instantly instead of use clicking or typing again.

**Live Working Demo:**

```js
$("#validationTooltip02").on('input', function() { //input[name='calc']
  let convFrom;
  if ($(this).prop("name") == "btc") {
    convFrom = "btc";
    convTo = "usd";
  } else {
    convFrom = "usd";
    convTo = "btc";
  }

  $.getJSON("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/usd.json",
    function(data) {
      var origAmount = parseFloat($("input[name='" + convFrom + "']").val());
      var exchangeRate = parseInt(data.bpi.USD.rate_float);
      let amount;
      if (convFrom == "btc")
        amount = parseFloat(origAmount * exchangeRate);
      else
        amount = parseFloat(origAmount / exchangeRate);
      $("input[name='" + convTo + "']").val(amount.toFixed(2));
            
      //Add here
      var a = parseFloat($('#a').val())
      var b = parseFloat($('#b').val())
      var final = a * b//final amount multiplied by 465
      $('#c').val(final.toFixed(2))
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://stacksnippets.net/scripts/snippet-javascript-console.min.js?v=1"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="number" name="btc" class="form-control" id="validationTooltip02" placeholder="BTC">

  <input type="number" name="usd" class="form-control" id="a" placeholder="USD" readonly>

  <input type="hidden" id="b" value="465">

  <input name="amount" class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="0.00000" id="c" aria-label="0.00000" readonly>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks alot for the instructions. For the decimals, it remains .00 and doesn't really give the correct number following the Multiplication, Example you get 103.30 in USD field which should be multiplied by 465 to get an answer in the the last input field that should be 48,034.5... The last input field instead returns 47895.00  Can you please help fix this?

Comment: @Aliu Please see my updated answer all working for you. Consider accepting my asnwer if i have solved the question in a better way and provided a full working solution.

Answer (score 0):

So, I think you should use your add function in the function you already call on `.form-control` keyup, like this:

```
$(".form-control").keyup(function() { //input[name='calc']
  let convFrom;
  if ($(this).prop("name") == "btc") {
    convFrom = "btc";
    convTo = "usd";
  } else {
    convFrom = "usd";
    convTo = "btc";
  }
  $.getJSON("https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice/usd.json",
    function(data) {
      var origAmount = parseFloat($("input[name='" + convFrom + "']").val());
      var exchangeRate = parseInt(data.bpi.USD.rate_float);      
      let amount;
      if (convFrom == "btc")
        amount = parseFloat(origAmount * exchangeRate);
      else
        amount = parseFloat(origAmount / exchangeRate);
      $("input[name='" + convTo + "']").val(amount.toFixed(2));
      
      // Here goes the content of the add function
      var x = parseInt(document.getElementById("a").value);
      var y = parseInt(document.getElementById("b").value)
      document.getElementById("c").value = x * y;
    });
});
```

Comment: However what i got works to an extent, the Multiplication answer does not include decimals, e.g 4785.2 instead it just approximates to 4786 which is wrong when dealing with BTC